# Excel MySQL Connector/ODBC

Tags: mysql, excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to make a connection to MySQL using Excel. I'm successfully able to connect via Oracle SQL developer, but i'm having trouble connecting via Excel using same credentials.

I've installed 'mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.5-winx64.msi' on my machine. Then i try to make a 'Data Source (ODBC)' connection from control panel. Then i click on Add > MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver > Data Source Configuration Tab. On this tab i've entered everything except 'Named Pipe'. Not sure what this is. Also, i've entered all same credentials from Oracle SQL Developer, except 'Service Name'. Not sure where to enter this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isnt a direct answer, but this may be useful for you in future. [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Where is your server located? Why not use TCP/IP?

Named pipes is for SQL Server and within the physical (virtual) machine. Not between peers (client and host).